# Junit Test of servlet with eclipse

Tags: java, servlets, junit

I'm not familiar with Junit testing. For example, how can I write a Unit test for this servlet?
I really don't know where to start, please!!!
Obviously he accesses the database and I don't know how to do the test to check if the credentials entered are present in the db. Could you give me an example about this servlet please?

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginPatient
 */
@WebServlet("/LoginPatient")
public class LoginPatient extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginPatient() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fiscal_code=request.getParameter("fiscal_code");
        String user_password= request.getParameter("user_password");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        ProfileManager pM=new ProfileManager();
        UserBean patient= pM.ReturnPatientByKey(fiscal_code, user_password);

        if(patient != null) {
            HttpSession session= request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute( "user" , patient);
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
            out.println("1");
        }

        else {
            out.println("0"); 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A unit test for this servlet should not actually access the DB. It should test that the servlet behaves correctly given the various results `ProfileManager` may return.

You need to use dependency injection so that you can mock `ProfileManager` in your unit test.

How you do this depends on your framework. In spring you would say:

```
@Component
public class LoginPatient extends HttpServlet {
   ...
   @Autowired
   public LoginPatient(ProfileManager profileManager) { ... }
   ...
}
```

Then in your test use Mockito (this is a sketch not compilable code)

```
public void testPresent() {
   // mock the request and response, and the session
   HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
   Session session = mock(HttpSession.class);
   when(req.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
   ...
   // you might want to mock the UserBean instance too
   ProfileManager pm = mock(ProfileManager.class);
   when(pm.ReturnPatientByKey("aCode", "aPassword")).thenReturn(new UserBean(...));
   LoginPatient servlet = new LoginPatient(pm);
   servlet.doPost(req, res);
   // verify that the session had the right things done to it
}
```